# How do I make the ellipse move along my polynomial equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, graphing-functions

My equation is located on the following url: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7iewlnmfwv

Basically trying to make my ellipse move on my polynomial equation. Almost, like a roller coaster.

I'm aiming for the vertex of my ellipse to be on the line of my polynomial equation. As well as move along that line when the value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a long way to go on a long roller coaster ride ...First you have not defined the shape of your roller coaster path!

Second.. to describe rolling  on a straight path without slipping, go with an exercise on cycloid motion.

Thirdly, learn up what are  natural or intrinsic equations of curves.

Fourthly, find out connection between locus of ellipse focus and constant mean curvature curves or DeLaunay Unduloids.

Good Luck!

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I actually didn't want to create a literal roller coaster ride. But instead, have the vertex of my ellipse slide along the line of my polynomial function.